# How to write a query that selects 9 rows randomly from database?

Tags: php, sql, random

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl_specialisation
     WHERE LENGTH(spec_specialise) < 20 ORDER BY spec_specialise LIMIT 9
```

add to this query

Comment: You probably need to say which database product you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM `tbl_specialisation`WHERE LENGTH(spec_specialise) < 20 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9 ";

Answer (score 0):

USE `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `tbl_specialisation`WHERE LENGTH(spec_specialise) < 20 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9 ";
```

Comment: "SELECT dr_image ,dr_name FROM  tbl_doctors WHERE dr_image IS NOT NULL AND dr_name IS NOT NULL ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4 ;" here  the non image  field is come  idont wand non image field how chnge the query

Comment: ("SELECT dr_image ,dr_name FROM  tbl_doctors WHERE dr_image !='' AND dr_name !='' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4 ;"); this is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear because you are asking 9 random fields but in SQL query you are trying to get 9 records. If you want to get 9 records from table then use following.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM `tbl_specialisation`WHERE LENGTH(spec_specialise) < 20 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 9 ";
```